# How to get phrase tables from word alignments?

Tags: machine-translation

The output of my word alignment file looks as such:

```
I wish to say with regard to the initiative of the Portuguese Presidency that we support the spirit and the political intention behind it . In bezug auf die Initiative der portugiesischen Präsidentschaft möchte ich zum Ausdruck bringen , daß wir den Geist und die politische Absicht , die dahinter stehen , unterstützen .   0-0 5-1 5-2 2-3 8-4 7-5 11-6 12-7 1-8 0-9 9-10 3-11 10-12 13-13 13-14 14-15 16-16 17-17 18-18 16-19 20-20 21-21 19-22 19-23 22-24 22-25 23-26 15-27 24-28
It may not be an ideal initiative in terms of its structure but we accept Mr President-in-Office , that it is rooted in idealism and for that reason we are inclined to support it .    Von der Struktur her ist es vielleicht keine ideale Initiative , aber , Herr amtierender Ratspräsident , wir akzeptieren , daß sie auf Idealismus fußt , und sind deshalb geneigt , sie mitzutragen .   0-0 11-2 8-3 0-4 3-5 1-6 2-7 5-8 6-9 12-11 17-12 15-13 16-14 16-15 17-16 13-17 14-18 17-19 18-20 19-21 21-22 23-23 21-24 26-25 24-26 29-27 27-28 30-29 31-30 33-31 32-32 34-33
```

How can I produce the phrase tables that are used by MOSES from this output?

Comment: Seems to be just a text reformatting problem, have you written any code yet?

Comment: See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/translate/phrase_based.py

Answer (score 3):

This isn't my area of specialty and I'm not familiar with Moses, but I found this after some searching.

I think you are looking for GIZA++.  You'll see GIZA++ listed in the "Training" section (left menu) on the Moses home page, as the second step. GIZA++ is briefly described in tutorial fashion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752043/is-there-a-tutorial-about-giza). Here are a few tutorial PowerPoint slides: http://www.tc.umn.edu/~bthomson/wordalignment/GIZA.ppt

Comment: actually the ppt and the SO site you've linked to have nothing to do with the phrase alignments. It only achieves the word alignments that I have showed in the original post. =(

Comment: Maybe so.  As I said, this isn't my area.  Did you try going through all the steps in the Tutorials and also the "Training" section?  It appears that they take you through all the steps, starting with source texts.  Best wishes.

Comment: it's the steps to get word alignments not phrases...

Comment: My impression was that the Tutorials and Training sections take you through all these steps, including phrase alignment.  I suggest going through all of them and you might discover which stage and tool accomplishes this task.

Answer (score 2):

I could try to explain you with words, but these slides explain it very well with pictures. Hope it helps.
http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/mt/lectures/phrase-model.pdf

Note this slides correspond to the chapter 5 of "Statistical Machine Translation" by Philipp Koehn, highly recommended if you are working on machine translation, and it is easy to read.

Comment: Answers that rely on external resources to be useful are strongly discouraged on Stack Exchange. If a link stops working, or a reference book is not available, these answers become useless. Please *do* explain with words, either by paraphrasing or quoting your sources directly, and upload images (with attribution) as necessary and appropriate, using external links and references only for citation and "further reading."

Comment: @keisZn, the pdf was a good explanation but there is no algorithm to explain how he parse through the alignment matrix to get consistent phrases...

Comment: does anyone have the algorithm to get the "consistent phrases"?